# How do I make my drop down remain dropped down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, drop-down-menu

The site I'm currently working on is located at:
http://counterbeing.com

The problem I'm trying to solve is that when you run your mouse over the "Categories" button, the sub-menu items pop up, but then disappear before you can click them.

I've tried a variety of things. For one thing, I was attempting to define the div that the sub menu items are wrapped in as something that will also trigger the animation, but that doesn't seem to work...

Here is the javascript file I'm using to grab both layers. I have it divided into 2 layers because one of them is somewhat transparent.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
($("div#CategoriesLink")||$("div#CategoryButtonHolder")).hover(function(){
    $("div#navdrop").animate({
        top: "0px"
    })
    $("div#CategoryButtonHolder").animate({
        top: "0px"
    })
}); 
$("div#CategoriesLink").mouseout(function(){        

    $("div#navdrop").animate({
        top: "-162px"
    })
    $("div#CategoryButtonHolder").animate({
        top: "-162px"
    })
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first thing is you don't need to use two divs if you use an rgba background on the CategoryButtonHolder.

Next, you're using a mouseout event handler to animate the div back up.  So every time you mouse leaves the button, you activate the mouseout. Try moving the mouseout handler to the CategoryButtonHolder.

```
$("#CategoryButtonHolder").mouseout(function(){
   $(this).animate({
       top: '-'+$(this).outerHeight()
   });
)};
```

Comment: I swapped the hard-coded 'top' value for the element's height.  It will always hide it completely, but you won't have to update the javascript every time the dimension changes.

Comment: I really like the way you chose not to hard code that. I'm also going to try to implement the RGBa background color you suggested...

Comment: Great. Let me know how it turns out.

Comment: turned out pretty well. I didn't completely follow your recommendations, but I see where you were going with that. But it is working now!. Another major thing I discovered was that I needed to use .mouseleave event rather than mouseout. Mouseout folded up my dropdown when you rolled over a button that was within the div i was dropping, doh!

Answer (score 0):

For hover, a nice plugin that solved that kind of problem was the hoverintent plugin: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html; you can make it wait and stay up for X ms time and its really smooth then.

HTH.